# FFMPEG preset question

Tags: ffmpeg, stream

I am trying to use [this sh](http://www.thegameengine.org/miscellaneous/streaming-twitch-tv-ubuntu/) to broadcast on twitch, but I keep getting this error

```
Unrecognized option 'preset=fast'
```

I am running Ubuntu 13.10, it is an ASUS laptop

Comment: Whoever made the script does not know what they are doing. They use `-qscale` but libx264 ignores that option. Even if it did support `-qscale` this option is mutually exclusive with `-b:b`. `-b 64KB` is used but `-b` is ambiguous and `-b:v` or `-b:a` should be used instead if you want to declare a specific bitrate. 64k is very low for video.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a change in 3rd line from end of script:

Change:

```
-vpre
```

to

```
-preset:v
```